# Which folder Chrome stores my history in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome

How can I view the webpages that Google Chrome returns in the history search? I'm trying to recover a deleted forum post and the only place it shows up is when you open the history tab and search for it. This means that it's somewhere on my computer.

I've read that Chrome uses an SQL table to store it's history, but when I open up the history DB (in `home/%USER%/.google-chrome/Default/History` and using SQLite DB browser), I can't find the source of the page anywhere.

Ideally, I'd like to open up the page as it was in the history. I'm using Linux Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Have you had a look at `archived history` and `History Index 20xx-xx` files ?

Answer (score 5):

1) Look in locations

~/.cache/

~/.config/google-chrome/

2) or open the following in address bar of chrome browser:

chrome://view-http-cache/

Answer (score 1):

Chrome most likely saves just the URL in browser history, it won't save the webpage as it was...

Making it will be impossible to recover that post through Chrome.

EDIT: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/261998/view-chrome-history-in-linux/261999#261999) will help you out? I haven't used it before but it looks like what you need.

Comment: but then, when you search for text, how does it show it? To be more precise, I'm trying to recover a forum post. It's no longer there on the actual site. When I search for a phrase in the post that I wrote through the history tab, it'll shows that snippet. This is why I think it's storing the page somewhere in the cache, or at least the text of the page

Comment: Interesting point, I never thought about that.

Comment: Updated my post with a possible solution.

Comment: It looks like you typed the incorrect link in your update

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Linux Mint 15 (codename Olivia), 64-bit MATE distribution.

I couldn't locate some of the pages I had browsed to using the browser's history feature.

I couldn't find the date in any of the folders mentioned in the answer either.

I could, however, retrace my history by going to http://www.google.com/history.

It's a bit unorthodox, but it did help me in my quest.